# ApacheBenchmark and Jmeter results vary a lot

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, apachebench

I ran ab and Jmeter. For ab I used 200 concurrency with a total of 20000 requests and for Jmeter 200 sized thread group for 100 loops. The results of the #requests/sec varied a lot. From ab I get ~1000 and Jmeter gives me 500 at max. Also while setting verbosity of the responses for the ab test I receive very few (~100) responses back. Is it the reason why abTest is performing better?

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260526/which-gets-the-measurements-right-jmeter-or-apache-ab) might help

Answer (score 2):

Are you following JMeter best practices when running your test:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

If not, then it explains your issues.

Another possibility is that you're not setting a startup delay of 10 seconds for JMeter to create the threads, which impacts then your test.

Comment: sorry the values shown by the two tests are still coming out to be different. I'm sticking to ab right now.

Comment: What excatly did you compare in the 2 runs ? ab vs jmeter and how did you proceed ?

Comment: Im comparing the Request per second parameter. The configs I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: can you show jmeter test plan including thread group config detail and show ab command line ? thx

Comment: I am currently tied up with some other issue, but will update it soon. Thanks.