# Differences between JMeter and Apache Benchmark

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, apachebench

I've been using JMeter for a long time and during my research, I came across Apache Benchmark, which seemed a bit more simple load testing tool to me.

So my assumption is that; Apache Benchmark is more suitable choice for benchmarking one API at a time. And it won't be a good choice -and maybe impossible- for performing an end-to-end load test.

But I am also curious about if A/B has any kind of advantages over JMeter in terms of performance / benchmark testing.

Could you please explain?

Thanks...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260526/which-gets-the-measurements-right-jmeter-or-apache-ab/10264501#10264501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to "hammering" the endpoint with simple HTTP Requests ab can be suitable alternative to JMeter as long as you're fine with the following limitations:

- no control regarding how connections are used/re-used
- no support of other [authentication types](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter/) than Basic (digest, NTLM, Kerberos)
- no control of [DNS caching](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager)
- no [clustered mode of tests execution](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- missing metrics like connect time, TTFB, etc. and in general results are quite "poor" comparing to JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

The only advantage of ab I can think of is lower CPU/Memory footprint